# Removed white spaces from a program but need to have white spaces at one point

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a input file which looks like:

> `059790355;61033755;026466086;19        ;NOMBRE GENERICO APELLIDO GENERICO                                                                   ;BAA;1CXX;1;2013-04-12;2014-02-12;352082056559802                                   ;`

When I run the program I get the output as:

> `059790355;61033755;026466086;19;NOMBREGENERICOAPELLIDOGENERICO;BAA;1CXX;1;2013-04-12;2014-02-12;352082056559802;`

But I require the output to be:

> `059790355;61033755;026466086;19;NOMBRE GENERICO APELLIDO GENERICO;BAA;1CXX;1;2013-04-12;2014-02-12;352082056559802;`

The name attribute should have white spaces.
My program is:

```
{
    System.out.println("Usage: APP <INPUT_FILE> <OUTPUT_FILE>");
    return;
}
    try {

        File fout = new File(args[1]);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

        File file = new File(args[0]);
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();     
        String line= bufferedReader.readLine();

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            line = line.trim();    
            line = line.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                bw.write(line);

            bw.newLine();
        }

        bw.close();
        fileReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Please be specific! Where exactly would you like to remove the whitespaces and where would you like to keep them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all the whitespace around semicolons:

```
line=line.replaceAll("\\s*;\\s*", ";");
```

This will turn strings like `foo; bar baz;   42 ;` into `foo;bar baz;42;`

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex replacement:

```
line = line.replaceAll("\\s+(?!\w)", "");
```

It replaces all whitespaces, which aren't followed by a word character (digit or alphabet or underscore) to nothing.

Also, remove `line = line.trim();`, it's unnecessary to have it since the regex will handle.

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gI3sK2/1)!